# Python - Merge Multiple 2D Arrays with Same Dimensions into One 2d Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have 3 2D numpy float arrays (**R, G, B**) with the same dimensions. I want to merge it in one 2d array, causing every element in the new 2d array to be an array of 3 floating numbers. Below is my initial code:

```
image = cv2.imread('hurricane katrina 1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

a = 255
b = 2 * (np.pi/255)
c = np.pi / 5


R = a * np.absolute(np.sin(b * image))
G = a * np.absolute(np.sin(b * image + c))
B = a * np.absolute(np.sin(b * image + 2 * c))
```

How will I do it in Python without iterating through the arrays? Thanks.

UPDATE:

I want to merge the 3 Arrays. Say for example

```
R[0][0] = 3 
G[0][0] = 4 
B[0][0] = 6
```

Then the merge array will be

```
RGB[0][0] = (3,4,6)
```

And this will be true for all elements in the arrays.

So the final output shape will be  `(1000,775,3)`

Comment: Merge and concat are literally the one and the same thing in case of numpy and lists..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.concatenate((a, b,c), axis=see what you want, probably 1)`

Or
You can also use hstack...( They both are one and the same thing...)

`Doing, rgb_transform = np.concatenate(R,G,B), throws an error. TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index,` 
But it shouldn't throw as I am already passing them in parenthesis

To resolve this, probably 
Do this
`np.concatenate([a, b, c], axis=see what you want, probably 1)`

Refer the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Edit

What was asked is a bit different than above, so the correct answer is to do 
`np.stack((r,g,b),2)` as the final output is `(1000,775,3)`...

Comment: Doing, rgb_transform = np.concatenate(R,G,B), throws an error. TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: You are missing the extra parenthesis, they are necessary @Eliyah

Comment: The first parameter to concatenate should itself be a sequence of arrays to concatenate...

Comment: Thanks, I tried rgb_transform = np.concatenate([R,G,B], axis=0, out=None) and turns out working. But my problem is not address, I want to merge, not concantenate.

Comment: What's your shape of r,g,b? This works perfectly for me if the shapes of them are like (x,1) Try it out on a sample random array and have a look

Comment: The 3 arrays shape is (1000, 775) and the output must be the same except for each element in the 2d array it must consist 3 numbers.

Comment: So your final output is (1000,775,3), if yes then you can do the same by using np.stack((r,g,b),2)

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you, you can edit your answer so that I can mark it right. :)